# Where should I store my mercurial repo on linux?

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial

I'd like to set up a mercurial repo on a linux machine. Originally, I was going to set it up in my home directory but a lot of different users are going to be accessing it so it doesn't seem like the best place. Can anybody recommend a better location? Or should I just go with the home dir and set the permissions accordingly?

Comment: which distro is that?

Comment: It's running Debian.

Answer (score 3):

`/srv` is the place recommended by the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM): "site-specific data which is served by this system."

Answer (score 2):

I think the "usual" place would be under /var/local..